# Creating website template which is independent from source code in asp.net webforms 

Tags: asp.net, templates, user-controls

Im working on an e-commerce platform which supports multiple stores on different domains. The backend is complete (for now) and I'm now starting the front-end part. Since the platform supports multiple stores I need some kind of templating system and I haven't quite figured out what's the best way to do this.

This are my requirements:

- I don't want to rebuild my solution to add a new template
- Templates are stored in /Templates/TemplateDirectoryName
- I want to be able to use (predefined) usercontrols inside the templates.
- I use URL routing and only have 1 Default.aspx page which controls which page template and additional code needs to be loaded.

This is what I came up with so far:

- In my template directory i have templates created with master pages (A homepage master file, a default master file, and sub-master files referencing the default master file...for product detail, browse, search etc)
- My Default.aspx page picks the right template based on routing values

While this way works I don't think it's very practical but the more I think about it the more I come to the conclusion that there are not so many other options to go around this. I think this is what I want to ask: Is there a way to use  usercontrols in a template and have the template completely seperated from the application so users can create templates without having to worry about the site's namespace and structure?

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: Interesting question ... I already asked to myself this question in the past, but I quickly changed my approach due to my lack of knowledge. +1 to perhaps enlighten me.

Comment: "The backend is complete (for now):" I fear that you have limited your choices by building out the back end already.  A framework-based solution would most likely entail a rewrite.

Comment: @ArtharAnis - When you get the chance let me know what you think of my answer.

Comment: Are you aware of the "Virtual Path Provider" technology from ASP.NET (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441/en-us)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are referencing a folder for templates, wouldn't it be possible to just change the .aspx files in the folder and asp.net shall pick up the template based on the url path that you've mentioned? I think that is possible in asp.net.
Also, Frameworks like DotNetNuke, Sharepoint, Joomla etc. have the similar concept. You can avail their features.

Answer (score 1):

My proposed solution is below.  It has a few constraints, like all master pages need to implement the same set of placeholder controls (not surprising).  Take a look and let me know what you think.

I setup my folder structure like this:

Website -> Templates -> TemplateFolder (named same as the template)
Website -> Templates -> UserControls (User controls are stored in a non-template specific folder)

I defined a simple Template configuration class which we can store/save/load a basic template deffinition:

```
public class Template
{
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
    public string UserControlName { get; set; }
    public string MasterPageName { get; set; }

    public string TemplateFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return GetTemplateFolder(TemplateName);
        }
    }

    public string TemplateConfigFile { get { return GetTemplateConfigFile(TemplateName); } }

    private static string GetTemplateFolder(string name)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Templates/" + name + "/");
    }

    private static string GetTemplateConfigFile(string name)
    {
        return GetTemplateFolder(name) + "/" + name + ".config";
    }

    public Template()
    {

    }

    public void Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Template));

        if (!Directory.Exists(TemplateFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(TemplateFolder);

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(TemplateConfigFile))
        {
            xs.Serialize(fs, this);
        }
    }

    public static Template Load(string name)
    {
        if(!File.Exists(GetTemplateConfigFile(name))) return null;

        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Template));

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(GetTemplateConfigFile(name)))
        {
            Template t = (Template)xs.Deserialize(fs);

            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

You can build some bare xml code to get started with by running the code below:

```
    Template t1 = new Template() { TemplateName = "Template1", MasterPageName = "Child1.master", UserControlName = "uc1.ascx" };
    Template t2 = new Template() { TemplateName = "Template2", MasterPageName = "Child2.master", UserControlName = "uc2.ascx" };

    t1.Save();
    t2.Save();
```

I created a basic master page.  This page will probably never be used except to give your default page the basic placeholders.  All of your master pages should have the same set of placeholders as your base one so that your pages can use them all interchangably.  Notice I left a placeholder for our user control.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BaseMaster.master.cs" Inherits="Templates_Masters_BaseMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphHeader" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cpUserControl" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphFooter" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I create a basic aspx web page that uses the above master page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Templates/Masters/BaseMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DefaultTemplated.aspx.cs" Inherits="DefaultTemplated" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHeader" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpUserControl" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphFooter" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

In the codebehind we'll setup the basic templating.  This sets the masterpage and adds a pre-defined user control to the content placeholder for user controls.  If you wanted you could just make a panel or something and add it to that fixed control, but I thought you might appreciate seeing how to make it work with masterpages.

```
public partial class DefaultTemplated : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Template PageTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tLoaded == null)
            {
                string template = Request.QueryString["template"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(template)) return null;

                Template t = Template.Load(template);
                _tLoaded = t;
            }

            return _tLoaded;
        }
    }

    private Template _tLoaded = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PageTemplate != null)
        {
            //cpUserControl is the name of my usercontrol placeholder
            ((ContentPlaceHolder)Page.Form.FindControl("cpUserControl")).Controls.Add(
                    Page.LoadControl("~/Templates/UserControls/" + PageTemplate.UserControlName));
        }
    }

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PageTemplate == null) return;

        this.MasterPageFile = "~/Templates/" + PageTemplate.TemplateName + "/" + PageTemplate.MasterPageName;
    }
}
```

If you had a template named "Template1" you could use it by calling "Default.aspx?template=Template1".  Since you are using URL rewriting you would use the rewriting to pass the template name as a parameter to the page.

Another option that could be combined with the above would be the use of Page.ParseControl.  Using this you could store your raw asp.net designer code (designer only) in a database or raw text file.  Then you could instantiate it load it like this:

```
//where pnl1 is a Panel on the page.  Page.ParseControl just returns a control object, so use it anywhere.
pnl1.Controls.Add(Page.ParseControl("raw asp.net designer code here."));
```

One great thing about this is that nested controls work great too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly:

If you don't want to rebuild, then I can tell a CMS concept is best suitable for you.

- You can store your templates as an HTML in database and from DB you can fetch it back,
- You can give an admin functionality with editor to edit your template online also.